# I made a platformer, but something went wrong

Tags: python, pygame

I have started with making a platformer, but my first attempt was a big failure.

The code is:

```
import pygame as p

p.init()
win = p.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

p.display.set_caption('Project')

player = [p.image.load('sprite/cube.jpg')]
bg = [p.image.load('sprite/bgone.jpg')]

clock = p.time.Clock()

x = 1280 / 2
y = 720 / 1.5
width = 56
height = 60
speed = 10
delaytime = 50
jump = False
jumpspeed = 10

anim = 0


def draw():
    global anim
    global x
    global y
    if anim + 1 >= 30:
        anim = 0
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(player, (x, y))
    p.display.update()


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            run = False

    k = p.key.get_pressed()
    if k [p.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x = x - speed
    if k [p.K_RIGHT] and x < (1280 - width - 5):
        x = x + speed
    if k [p.K_a] and x > 5:
        x = x - speed
    if k [p.K_d] and x < (1280 - width - 5):
        x = x + speed
    if k [p.K_SPACE]:
        jump = True
    if not jump:
        bhop = False
    if jump:
        speed = 15
        if jumpspeed >= -10:
            if jumpspeed < 0:
                y += (jumpspeed ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpspeed ** 2) / 2
            jumpspeed -= 1
        else:    
            jump = False
            jumpspeed = 10
            speed = 10
    draw()
p.quit()
quit()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "it dosen't matter", line 68, in <module>
    draw()
  File "it dosen't matter", line 30, in draw
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
```

I don't know what is this. I watched a lot of videos but nobody helped, so i tried ALL ide's i know, but all give that error. Tried to re-write the programm, but still i see this. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code? People may be reluctant to follow external links.

Comment: You're going to struggle to get random strangers on the internet to click a download link. You need to make a [mcve] instead

Comment: From the error message it sounds like `bg` is supposed to be an instance of `pygame`, but it's a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: if you call `blit()` the first argument has to be a `Surface`, not a list.

Looking at your code

```
bg = [p.image.load('sprite/bgone.jpg')]
...
win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
```

we see that you indeed pass a list as first argument to the `blit` function.

It's not clear why you put the background image into a list in the first place, so just change your code to

```
bg = p.image.load('sprite/bgone.jpg').convert()
...
win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
```

`convert()` ensures the `bg`-Surface has the same pixel format as the display Surface, which is important for the game's performance.